# Pass stringbuilder from one activity to the other

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass a **listview with checkboxes** of city names as the items from one activity to the other. I am retrieving the checked cities successfully  in a StringBuilder.
The problem lies when i try to transfer the stringbuilder object from one activity to the other. Any Help wud be appreciated..

The Java File:

```
public class TailoredtwoActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener{

    StringBuilder builder;
    Button btn1;
    ListView mListView;
    String[] array = new String[] {"Ham", "Turkey", "Bread"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tailoredtwo);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, array);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewcity);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tailortwo_submit);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        SparseBooleanArray positions = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            if(positions.get(index)==true)
            {
                builder.append(array[index]);
                builder.append(" ");
            }
        }
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this, TailoredthreeActivity.class);
        i1.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, builder);
        startActivity(i1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: and where is the problem? it should run since `StringBuilder` is `Serializable` ... did you tried `Intent.getSerializableExtra(...)` and cast it to `StringBuilder` in second activity ... of course blackbelt's solution is better here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the whole `StringBuilder`, you can pass the string that the `StringBuilder` holds. In the other `Activity` retrieve that `String` and create a new `StringBuilder` with

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(currentString);
```